# Customizing 'Add to cart' in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using ***WooCommerce 2.1.12***

I have successfully changed the text of `Add to cart` to `Place Order`.
I have made a custom page called `Place Order`. What I need is, when the customer clicks the `Place Order` button, he is taken to the `Place Order` page and no `Add to cart` stuff should work. 

How can I do this ? Please guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkout tab under the settings for woocommerce where you can select which page you want to use for each step of the checkout process.  It should let you select any of your pages here.

Answer (score 0):

So one option that you could try would be installing this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/). Obviously, not the ideal situation, as it creates a bloated system running so many plugins.

Another option is found [here](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-skip-product-cart-pages/). Essentially, hard-coding the permalinks of your products with the 'add-to-cart' functionality, like so:

```
http://your-site.com/?add-to-cart=37
```

where the 37 is the product ID. You could create a loop on the page cycling through all products, and placing that ID into each link.

From there, you'll need to add some code into your functions.php

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_to_checkout');

function woo_redirect_to_checkout() {
   global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using my free plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/), just set "Custom Add to Cart Text" and "Redirect to Page" option will do.